# Orchard 1.7 MediaLibrary Image on Contenttype display in alternate shape

Tags: image, media, orchardcms, media-library

i'm using orchard 1.7 and made a content definition with some input fields and a media library picker field which should be used to simply choose a image which will be displayed in a list.
(for example a list of references)
i then created a projection with a query to display all the information. but i just don't get how i can access the media library picker image.
i tried the different layout options, as well as finding the image with the shape tracing module. but there is no Property like MediaUrl, just the Name of the Field. so how can i display the image?

thanks

Comment: Same issue here - did you find a fix?

Comment: Unfourtunately not yet...hope there is a solution for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do this.

Basically you have to use the placement.info file of your theme. You need to add `<Place Fields_MediaLibraryPicker="Content:1" /> <!-- this adds the field.. -->` into your Summary.

So in my case my placement.info now contains this:

```
    <Match DisplayType="Summary">
       <Place Parts_Common_Metadata_Summary="-"/>
       <Place Parts_Title="-"/>
       <Place Fields_MediaLibraryPicker="Content:1" /> <!-- this adds the field.. -->       
   </Match>
```

Comment: @Daren, Is this possible without using placement.info? I have 2 MediaLibraryPicker Fields on my content type. I want to swap the images on hover, so will need some custom html to do that.

Comment: Honestly @Yash i have no idea.. it's been a while since i played with Orchard. I find it quite awkward to develop with. Very good CMS and full-featured, though for me, it's an ass to do some simple things.